# Post multipart data in python with Requests module

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I actually want to send mutlipart data on a web-application with python. I'm using this wery useful Requests module (http://requests-fr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

I have to send an audio file (stored in local on the system) and 2 parameters (GPS coordonates for information).

I have already mannage to do this with a curl command, but i'm looking for a Requests python implementation.
This is the curl command:

`curl  -u "user:pass" -F 'audio=@file.wav' -F "latitude=42.44646" -F "longitude=8.46464" 'http://my_server_ip/web/rest/vocal' -v --digest`

This is how i'm trying to do that in python Requests:

```
url = "http://my_server_ip/web/rest/vocal"
files = {'audio' : open('/PATH/record.wav','rb'),'latitude':42.44646,'longitude':8.46464}

r = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user','pass'),data=files)
r.json
print r.json
```

For the moment, the only response i get is a 500 error.

Does someone understand what's wrong ? Feel free to tell me if you see a better solution to do that :)

Greetings!

Comment: Have you tried `...files=files)` in your post instead of `...data=files)`?

Comment: Yes ! with files=files, i get a 400 error

Comment: http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file I assume `latitude`, `longitude` are not files, so they should not be keys in the `files` `dict`...

Comment: Exact !

`files = {'audio' : open('/PATH//record.wav','rb')}

data = {'latitude':latitude,'longitude':longitude}

r=requests.post(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user','pass'),files=files,data=data)`

This works good ! My bad, i didn't think about something this "easy" ! Thanks you @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

The solution is to separate the files and the datas like that:

```
files = {'audio' : open('/PATH//record.wav','rb')} 
data = {'latitude':latitude,'longitude':longitude}
```

And build the resquest wit BOTH files AND data parameters:

```
r=requests.post(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user','pass'),files=files,data=data)
```